# Logging in to Data Explorer (SEDE) in another window changes name in the first

Tags: bug, data-explorer, login, user-accounts, display-names

When writing a question a few minutes ago, I logged into Data Explorer in a private window. When I logged back into it in a normal window, **my username had changed** to "Stormblessed31729" due to not being unique. Even after logging out of the private window, it was still allegedly not unique. Logging back in in the private window, it was still Stormblessed there.

Changing it to something else there then changing it back in the normal window fixed it.

**This is a weird bug and likely a symptom of another problem. I'd like it to be fixed at some point, please.**

Comment: are these your accounts: [stormblessed](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/31728/stormblessed) and [stormblesseda](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/30191/stormblesseda)? Did you create a new account that got userid 31729? It is unclear what you did but user management sometimes gets derailed, leading to new accounts and no longer being able to use older ones. Do you still have access to the other accounts? And what did you do with that new account?